# Accordion using JQuery is not showing images in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have an accordion style feature section on a home page that is working correctly in IE 7/8, FF, Opera, and Chrome but not in IE 9. The site is live at http://ntwo.com. I have tried using different versions of JQuery (v1.4.1,v1.4.2,v1.5.1,v1.5.1rc1) and none have corrected the issue. I must mention that it works correctly *sometimes*.

The behavior is as follows:
When it operates as expected, the 5 images preload and then are displayed from left to right once finished loading. While the images are preloading, a "loading" image is shown rotating in their respective places. All images are .png files, however, I have tested with jpeg as well with the same results. When I said it works correctly *sometimes*...It appears that sometimes when clicking the refresh button or the home link or the logo will cause it to work correctly, but then if you refresh again after that, it usually will not work the next time. When it fails to work the "loading" images simply rotate continually, but the final images never show.

Following code is what I am using to preload the images: (the full js file is at http://ntwo.com/scripts/custom.js)

```
{
$.fn.super_image_preloader = function (options)
{
    var defaults = {
        repeatedCheck: 550,
        fadeInSpeed: 1100,
        delay: 200,
        callback: ''
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    return this.each(function ()
    {
        var imageContainer = jQuery(this),
            images = imageContainer.find('img').css(
            {
                opacity: 0,
                visibility: 'hidden'
            }),
            imagesToLoad = images.length;
        imageContainer.operations = {
            preload: function ()
            {
                var stopPreloading = true;
                images.each(function (i, event)
                {
                    var image = $(this);
                    if (event.complete == true)
                    {
                        imageContainer.operations.showImage(image);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        image.bind('error load', {
                            currentImage: image
                        }, imageContainer.operations.showImage);
                    }
                });
                return this;
            },
            showImage: function (image)
            {
                imagesToLoad--;
                if (image.data.currentImage != undefined)
                {
                    image = image.data.currentImage;
                }
                if (options.delay <= 0) image.css('visibility', 'visible').animate(
                {
                    opacity: 1
                }, options.fadeInSpeed);
                if (imagesToLoad == 0)
                {
                    if (options.delay > 0)
                    {
                        images.each(function (i, event)
                        {
                            var image = $(this);
                            setTimeout(function ()
                            {
                                image.css('visibility', 'visible').animate(
                                {
                                    opacity: 1
                                }, options.fadeInSpeed);
                            }, options.delay * (i + 1));
                        });
                        if (options.callback != '')
                        {
                            setTimeout(options.callback, options.delay * images.length);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (options.callback != '')
                    {
                        (options.callback)();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        imageContainer.operations.preload();
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

I don't know if this is where the problem is or not, any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Your brace style makes me want to kill someone (e.g. you). Your code is pretty much unreabable without jsbeautifier.

Comment: I'm the **end-user** of this code, not something I wrote. I'm not a js developer, "yet". This was originally all in one line of code. I did what I could with my limited knowledge, just ran it through jsbeautifier, I will update it. Thanks for sharing that with me.

Comment: JQuery 1.5.1 is the proper version to use; it's the first IE9 compatible version. Have you watched your network traffic (e.g. with Fiddler) to ensure that all of the images are getting downloaded?

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT-, Thanks for the tip on Fiddler. Yes the images are being downloaded. I am currently using JQuery 1.5.1

Comment: @eupton: ok, then s/you/the developer of the code/ ;)

Comment: I wish I could use the developer, but it is from a purchased template, with no indication of the developer. I've contacted the site from which I purchased it, but haven't received a response.

Comment: May be the problem is with the dimensions of the images not being calculated correctly by the browser, try to inspect the values and if this is the case you can use something like $('img').load(function(){$(this).width=_width_;$(this).height=_height_}); to update the size of the image after they are loaded by the browser

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I corrected it by removing the fade in effect for the images. For now this is a work around.

Comment: @eupton: did you found the problem? I too have an old code that stopped showing images in IE9. I'm blaming the IE filters but does JQuery 1.5 uses the filters? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the person who says you should change your brace style is probably on to something.
First try changing your braces so that they follow K&R style (opening brace on the same line as condition / function, instead of dangling on its own line). Using Allman style in Javascript can actually cause code not to work: http://encosia.com/2011/03/21/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/ . I'd start with that and see if it fixes anything. Other things to keep in mind is IE9 has a JS culling engine that removes code that it doesn't thing is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Uff, I spent LOT of time solving this, seems that we were using same code for accordion (same mess) - found it in Kaleidoscope web design template (http://www.templatesold.com/templates/items/5994/kaleidoscope---html-template.html). At first, in IE 9 images was loading after push F5 for a few times (cache empty) so I put into .htacces *ExpiresByType text/html A0* but lately I found that was not the good solution... Internet Explorer 10 was displaying just white spaces (like the images was hidden)

After debugging i found that mistake is in jquery´s **super_image_preloader** plugin, there, around row 188 I just replaced preload function with help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery#answers-header) answer

```
preload:function(){
                    images.each(function(i,event){
                            var image=$(this);
                            var imageSrc=$(this).attr("src");
                            $('<img/>')[0].src = imageSrc;
                            imageContainer.operations.showImage(image);
                        });
                    return this;
                }
```